# Talking about what a person used to do when they were alive

Tags: grammar

If I were to ask someone if the person they knew, used to do something before their death, should I ask it like this:

> Did he use to wear a hat while playing football?

Or should it be:

> Did he used to wear a hat while playing football?

Or should it completely be a different structure for talking about something like this?

Comment: 'Did he use...?' Never 'Did he used...?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Merriam-Webster dictionary,

> Used to refers to something familiar or routine, as in "I'm used to getting up early for work," or to say that something repeatedly happened in the past like "we used to go out more." Use to typically occurs with did; "did you use to work there?" or "it didn't use to be like that," describing something in the past that doesn't happen anymore.